# MongoDB C# Driver: Query interceptors?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Does the MongoDB C# driver support query interceptors like Entity Framework?

I've checked the documentation but can't find anything.

Basically what I need to do is ensure that certain queries to the database, depending on context, always have certain restrictions applied.

For example, if my documents can be soft deleted then I always need to make sure a filter is added for { "SoftDeleted": false }. Entitity Framework handles this gracefully via query interceptors.

Comment: Paging @CraigWilson :)

Comment: The answer is no it doesn't support entity framework

Comment: @MichaelRandall Hi, sorry I think you've misunderstood my question, it's not about Entity Framework

Answer (score 5):

`MongoClient` allows subscribing to `CommandStartedEvent`. Here is a sample that dumps to console each command sent to the server:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
    ClusterConfigurator = cb =>
    {
        cb.Subscribe<CommandStartedEvent>(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.CommandName} - {e.Command.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { Indent = true })}");
            Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 32));
        });
    }
});
```

`CommandStartedEvent` contains `CommandName` and `Command` properties that you could use for your specific logic.

Comment: Thanks. I can't see any way of modifying the command to be sent via this method though. Also I'd greatly prefer if there was a way to modify the LINQ query rather than a BsonDocument because then I can port/reuse some existing code, not to mention it'll be easier for existing developers who are more used to LINQ.

Comment: No, you can't modify the command with the method I have described. And I believe there is no query interceptors analogue for MongoDB .Net Driver. There is a good reason for it. Query interceptors are useful with EF because they give you a way to control the queries sent to DB. But MongoDB .Net Driver is a low-level client to the database. You don't need additional mechanism to control the queries because you can achieve it in first place with filter builders. MongoDB .Net Driver is very similar to ADO.NET Data Provider (`DbCommand`), for which query interceptors would also be useless concept.